# How can I maximise a video in a tiled window only?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, video, chrome

Say I have 3 windows tiled on my workspace.

1. A vim terminal session tiled vertically on the right
2. A pdf tiled in the top left corner
3. A youtube video playing in chrome and tiled in the bottom left corner

[Here's a screenshot of my workspace](https://imgur.com/ueRmK9k)

Is there a way to maximise the video to the size of the chrome tile? Currently I play videos in theatre mode, but there's still a lot of unused screen real estate wasted by the address bar and my bookmark bar for example.

I use Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1, im using whatever the default windows manager is (I'm sorry, I have no idea what it is)

Comment: I have edited my question. I use Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1, im using whatever the default windows manager is (I'm sorry, I have no idea what it is)

Comment: So you basically want full-screen video. You just want the "screen" to only be the lower right quadrant.

Comment: Yes that's right